# RuntimeError: liblsl library found but could not be loaded - possible platform/architecture mismatch

Tags: python, windows

I cannot run Python script which uses [`pylsl`](https://github.com/chkothe/pylsl) package on Windows. This package uses [`liblsl`](https://github.com/sccn/liblsl) library and requires `PYLSL_LIB` environment variable to be set to its shared library. I have `PYLSL_LIB` variable set to `.../liblsl-1.16.0-Win_amd64/bin/lsl.dll` library file which I have downloaded from the releases page [here](https://github.com/sccn/liblsl/releases/tag/v1.16.0).

1. I have Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable installed.
2. I am using 64 bit machine and 64 bit `liblsl` build.
3. It works fine on Linux (Debian 11). In this case I have built shared library from source as `liblsl` does not offer appropriate release.

How is this an issue with the architecture or the platform? What is an actual cause of this error and how could I fix it?

Below is an error that I got when running the script through Wine on Python 3.8, though I get the same mismatch error on Windows 10.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pylsl\pylsl.py", line 1279, in <module>
    lib = CDLL(libpath)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 373, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 193] Bad EXE format for %1

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\<...>\test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pylsl import StreamInlet, resolve_stream, examples
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pylsl\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .pylsl import IRREGULAR_RATE, DEDUCED_TIMESTAMP, FOREVER, cf_float32,\
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pylsl\pylsl.py", line 1293, in <module>
    raise RuntimeError(err_msg + "\n " + __dload_msg)
RuntimeError: liblsl library '/home/<...>/liblsl-1.16.0-Win_amd64/bin/lsl.dll' found but could not be load
ed - possible platform/architecture mismatch.
 You may need to download and install the latest Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable.
 You can install the LSL library with conda: `conda install -c conda-forge liblsl`
or otherwise download it from the liblsl releases page assets: https://github.com/sccn/liblsl/releases
0104:fixme:kernelbase:AppPolicyGetProcessTerminationMethod FFFFFFFA, 0032F350
```